# How to update related data in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I have an Entity Territory

```
public partial class Territory
{
    public Territory()
    {
        this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }

    public string TerritoryID { get; set; }
    public string TerritoryDescription { get; set; }
    public int RegionID { get; set; }

    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

And I have an Entity region

```
public partial class Region
{
    public Region()
    {
        this.Territories = new HashSet<Territory>();
    }

    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    public string RegionDescription { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Territory> Territories { get; set; }
}
```

On my Client application I make objects of Territory class and Region class to insert and update data in database and pass those objects to my AddTerriory and UpdateTerriory method in my repository class.

```
Territory obj = new Territory();
obj.TerritoryID = "12123";
obj.TerritoryDescription = "test terriotry 1";
obj.RegionID = 9;
obj.Region = new Region{RegionDescription = "test region 1"};

public void UpdateTerriory(Territory territory)
{
       using (var context = new travelEntities())
       {
                context.Territories.Attach(territory);
                context.Entry(territory).State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
}

    public static void AddTerriory(Territory territory)
    {
            using (var context = new travelEntities())
            {
                context.Territories.Add(territory);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
    }
```

But its not working and its throwing errors. How should I build my objects when I have to update and insert Territory and Region. 
At times some fields of Region are also updated when updating Territory, so I have to update that too. 
And when we add a new Territory then we add a new region too. We don't use existing Region when adding a new Territory.

How should I build my objects when I have to update and insert Territory and Region??

Edited: I am using Entity Framework 6 DB First with Oracle 11i as the back end.

Answer (score 0):

First off, why would you use string representation of territory identifier? Can it be integer?

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(Territory territory) 
{ 
    using (var context = new TravelEntities()) 
    { 
        context.Entry(territory).State = 
                      string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(territory.TerritoryID) ? 
                                   EntityState.Added : 
                                   EntityState.Modified; 
        if (territory.Region!=null)
        {
             context.Entry(territory.Region).State = 
                      territory.Region.RegionID == 0 ? 
                                   EntityState.Added : 
                                   EntityState.Modified;
        }


        context.SaveChanges(); 
    } 
}
```

you can make this method as a generic one, taking entity and key selector function as parameters.

Comment: I tried to  update with this new method  Territory obj1 = new Territory();
            obj1.TerritoryID = "12125";
            obj1.TerritoryDescription = "test terriotry 2";
            obj1.RegionID = 11;
            obj1.Region = new Region { RegionID = 11, RegionDescription = "test region 20" };
TerritoryRepository.InsertOrUpdate(obj1);                          If I am adding an object then it is throwing an error on context.SaveChanges(); Error: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted.

Comment: I am getting an error on context.SaveChanges() Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted